# ExtGWT import excel sheet

Tags: gxt

I am using **ExtGWT**. my requirement is i need to keep import button. as and when import is clicked user should be able to import an **excel** sheet into the application. and the excel data should be displayed in Gxt grid. please suggest me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use [POI](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html) for the excel import.  Set up a servlet that accepts the excel document, translates it into your data model and then send the data model back to the client.

I haven't done that specifically, but POI is pretty easy to use, and well documented.